# Clone partial git repo with go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

My golang application needs to list all file and folder paths in a subfolder of a git repo (a search path).  I only care about the HEAD commit.  I'm using the [go-git library](https://github.com/go-git/go-git) to clone the repo and iterate over the objects in the HEAD tree, listing their name.

```
repo, _ = git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), nil, git.CloneOptions{URL: repoUrl, Depth: 1})
// Get commit object at HEAD
// get tree of commit object
// iterate into tree and append file names if file is within my search path
```

This works but the clone operation is very slow as the repo gets large and probably gives me a ton of stuff I don't need (I'm only interested in a subset of the repo tree).  I noticed that the [git clone docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) have a `--filter` option that could serve my purposes.  Is this option available via the go-git library? I don't see anything in the [CloneOptions object](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/master/options.go#L37-L67)